# Как смантировать определенный сетевой диск в зависимости от точки доступа WiFi?

Tags: macos, mount, applescript

Предполагается использовать AppleScript для автоматического монтирования сетевых дисков. Как написать скрипт, чтобы в зависимости от точки доступа WiFi к которой в данный момент подключен Mac менялся адрес сетевого диска?

Скажем:

```
property myDisks : {"AirDisk 500GB", "AirDisk 320"}

set mountedDisks to paragraphs of (do shell script "/bin/ls /Volumes")
repeat with aDisk in myDisks
   if aDisk is not in mountedDisks then

   #    если WiFi = "Вася"
   #        mount volume "afp://airport-extreme-1.local/AirDisk 500GB"
   #    иначе WiFi = "Федя"
   #        mount volume "afp://airport-extreme-2.local/AirDisk 320"

   end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось усиленно гуглить и напрягать мозг. Но добился чего хотел!

```
set mySSID to do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | awk '/ SSID/ {print substr($0, index($0, $2))}'"

if ((mySSID as string) is equal to "ssid1") then
mountVolume("AFPVolume", "192.168.200.20", "user1", "pass1", "/Volumes/AFPVolume")
else if ((mySSID as string) is equal to "ssid2") then
    mountVolume("NAS", "192.168.200.30", "user2", "pass2", "/Volumes/NAS")

    .
    .
    .


end if

on mountVolume(serverPath, serverName, serverUser, serverPassword, localNode)
    if isMounted(localNode) then
        return
    end if
    set networkProtocol to "afp"
    if createLocalNode(localNode) then
        set mountURL to networkProtocol & "://" & serverUser & ":" & serverPassword & "@" & serverName & "/" & serverPath
        do shell script "mount -t " & networkProtocol & space & quoted form of mountURL & space & quoted form of localNode
    end if
end mountVolume

on createLocalNode(localNode)
    if not fileExists(localNode) then
        do shell script "mkdir " & quoted form of localNode & "; echo $?"
        return fileExists(localNode)
    end if
    if (do shell script "ls -A " & quoted form of localNode & " | wc -l") as integer is 0 then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end if
end createLocalNode

on unMount(localNode)
    if not isMounted(localNode) then
        return
    end if
    do shell script "diskutil unmount " & quoted form of localNode
end unMount

on fileExists(posixPath)
    return not ((do shell script "test -e " & quoted form of posixPath & "; echo $?") as integer) as boolean
end fileExists

on isMounted(localNode)
    return (do shell script "mount") contains (" on " & localNode & " (")
end isMounted
```